# Can I recover Chocolatey from corrupted Win10

Tags: windows-10, chocolatey

I have a corrupted win10 install that won't boot. I can read the hdd just fine. I would like to quickly recover and reinstall all the Chocolatey packages.

1. Is there a way to recover the list of locally installed Chocolatey
   packages?
2. Will the chocolatey package configuration survive a
   Windows10 reset?

Comment: Windows 10 Reset will purge all application settings.  The only applications that will be kept are Universal Windows Program (UWP) applications.

Comment: Thanks for answering my easy question. Any ideas on the first question?